# Add shapes to existing canvas from a MenuItem

Tags: android

having a canvas with a shape drawn into it, I want to add another shape (e.g another line) when I click a MenuItem. I have not found the way to do it. This is a simplified code to try to find a solution:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new MyView(this));   
    }

    public class MyView extends View {
        public MyView(Context context){
            super(context);
        }

        @Override protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        Paint myPaint=new Paint();
        myPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        myPaint.setStrokeWidth(8);
        canvas.drawLine(200,300,280,450,myPaint);
        }
    }

    @Override public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menuP){
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu,menuP);
        return true;
    }

    @Override public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem option_menu){
        int id=option_menu.getItemId();
        if(id==R.id.addDraw)
        {   
            //Add method to draw another shape
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(option_menu);
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the color you must also save the color along with the path. You can achieve this in various ways like using two lists, but I prefer to use a Class instead. Below is the implementation.

Create a `ColoredPath` class to hold both the path and its color. Instead of color you can also store the complete Paint object as well. It will help if you would like changing other things as well like stroke width for each path.

NOTE : I have given a simple class here, you may want to use getter and setter to access members, for good code quality.

```
public class ColoredPath{
 Path path; // stores the path
 int color; // stores the color
 
 // constructor for initialisation
 public ColoredPath(Path path, int color){
   this.path = path;
   this.color = color;
 }
}
```

Modify your custom view accordingly

```
public class MyView extends View {
        List<ColoredPath> paths = new ArrayList<>();    // list stores colored path instead of simple path
        public MyView(Context context){
            super(context);
            // you can add the initial path here
            Path path = new Path();
            path.moveTo(200f,300f);
            path.lineTo(280f, 450f);
            // create a colored path of our initial line
            ColoredPath coloredPath = new ColoredPath(path, Color.BLUE);
            paths.add(coloredPath);
        }
    }
```

Modify `onDraw()` accordingly

```
@Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        for (ColoredPath coloredPath : paths) {
            myPaint.setColor(coloredPath.color);   // change color for each path
            canvas.drawPath(coloredPath.path, myPaint);
        }
    }
```

Modify `addPath()` method

```
public void addPath(ColoredPath path) {
            paths.add(path);
            invalidate();   
        }
```

Comment: Sorry, it works perfectly in the example (than is an activity) but in the real project the view class and onDraw method are inside a fragment. It draws the first path without problems but when adding the second path the invalidate() method doesn't calls onDraw. Is there anything to take in mind with a fragment instead an activity. Thank you.

Comment: I am not aware of anything specific for fragment. Maybe you should ask it as a separate question with the code of your fragment. Maybe that will help.

Comment: Ok, thank, you.

Answer (score 2):

To force redrawing you must call `invalidate()`. It will cause `onDraw()` method to be called again, so you need to save whatever you have drawn until then and redraw everything with new shape you want. Below is a way to do this.

**Tip :** Do all your initialization outside `onDraw()` method for better performance.

1. Create a list to store you paths.

```
 public class MyView extends View {
        List<Path> paths = new ArrayList<>();    // the list stores all your path
        Paint myPaint = new Paint();    // initialize the paint
        myPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        myPaint.setStrokeWidth(8);
        public MyView(Context context){
            super(context);
            // you can add the initial path here
            Path path = new Path();
            path.moveTo(200f,300f);
            path.lineTo(280f, 450f);
            paths.add(path);
        }
    }
```

2. Expose a public method to add path to your list

```
 public addPath(Path path){
    paths.add(path);
    invalidate();   // call invalidate to force re-drawing
 }
```

3. Change your onDraw method to draw whatever is in the list

```
 @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        for (Path p : paths) {
            canvas.drawPath(p, myPaint);
        }
    }
```

4. Create an object of your custom view

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private MyView canvasView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        canvasView = new MyView(this);
        setContentView(canvasView);   
    }
}
```

5. Add a new path to you canvasView when needed

```
@Override public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem option_menu){
        int id=option_menu.getItemId();
        if(id==R.id.addDraw)
        {   
            Path path = new Path(); // new path object
            // create the required shape using this path
            path.moveTo(5f,5f);
            path.lineTo(10f,10f);
            path.addCircle(10f, 10f, 5f, Path.Direction.CCW);
            
            // add the path to the canvasView
            canvasView.addPath(path);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(option_menu);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much  for your detailed answer, Pawan. I'm going to check it and I'll comment the result.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have tried your solution (@Pawan) and had to make some changes as, for instance, to put myPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE); and change place of some initialitations. Now it draws the first path, but not the added paths after clicking the menu. And if I want to change the color of the second path , where must I do it?.
This is my actual code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private MyView canvasView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        canvasView = new MyView(this);
        setContentView(new MyView(this));
    }

    public class MyView extends View {
        List<Path> paths = new ArrayList<>();    // the list stores all your path
        Paint myPaint = new Paint();    // initialize the paint
     /*   myPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        myPaint.setStrokeWidth(8);*/

        //Expose a public method to add path to your list
        public void addPath(Path path) {
            paths.add(path);
            invalidate();   // call invalidate to force re-drawing
        }

        public MyView(Context context) {
            super(context);

            /**/  myPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            /**/  myPaint.setStrokeWidth(8);
            /**/  myPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            // you can add the initial path here
            Path path = new Path();
            path.moveTo(200f, 300f);
            path.lineTo(280f, 450f);
            paths.add(path);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            for (Path p : paths) {
                canvas.drawPath(p, myPaint);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menuP) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menuP);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem opcion_menu) {
        int id = opcion_menu.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.addDraw) {
            Path path = new Path(); // new path object
            // create the required shape using this path
            path.moveTo(210f, 310f);
            path.lineTo(290f, 460f);
            // add the path to the canvasView
            canvasView.addPath(path);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(opcion_menu);
    }
}
```

Comment: Debugging the code I have noticed than after invoking 'invalidate()' is not executed onDraw method.

Comment: Solved the problem of drawing added paths, it was my fault: instead of  setContentView(new MyView(this));  it must be  setContentView(canvasView); What about changing color of second path, where must I put the code?